# JQuery UI Autocomplete dropdown not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a search input box that gives out suggestions while user types. However, the dropdown that contains the suggested search is not showing.

What I've tried:

1. Adding `z-index: 100 !important;` to the main css.
2. Replacing jquery-2.1.4.js with https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js and calling the search functions inside my HTML instead. The search functions are called when the document is ready.
3. Checking if the JSON file that contains the possible results are being loaded.

So far, no. 2 is the only one that worked. However, I don't want to change my version of JQuery.

Below are the codes:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Auto complete Dropdown</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/activities.css">

  <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.js" defer></script>

  <script src="lib/jquery-ui.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="searchBar" tabindex="-1">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="ui-autocomplete" placeholder="Search for Blocks" tabindex="-1">
      <ul class="ui-menu" id="searchResults"></ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
doSearch = function () {
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

       $j('#search').autocomplete({
            source: searchSuggestions
       });

    $j('#search').autocomplete('widget').addClass('scrollSearch');
};

showSearchWidget = function () {

        if (searchWidget.style.visibility === 'visible') {
            hideSearchWidget();
        } else {
            var obj = docByClass('ui-menu');
            if (obj.length > 0) {
                obj[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
            }

            searchWidget.value = null;
            docById('searchResults').style.visibility = 'visible';
            searchWidget.style.visibility = 'visible';
            searchWidget.style.left = palettes.getSearchPos()[0] * turtleBlocksScale + 'px';
            searchWidget.style.top = palettes.getSearchPos()[1] * turtleBlocksScale + 'px';

            searchBlockPosition = [100, 100];

            // Give the browser time to update before selecting
            // focus.
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.debug('DO SEARCH!!!');
                searchWidget.focus();
                doSearch();
            }, 500);
        }
    };
```

CSS:

```
#search[type=text] {
    width: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 20px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: black;
}

#search:focus {
    border: 2px solid #87CEFA;
}

.ui-menu {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
  max-width: 250px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to call `doSearch` manually. The autocomplete displays suggestions when the user starts typing in it.

Comment: I removed ```doSearch``` under ```showSearchWidget```, however, the dropdown is still not showing...

Comment: You normally initialize autocomplete on page load i.e. `$(function() { $('#search').autocomplete(...); });`. Your code looks complicated and I don't understand why.

Comment: @SalmanA Hello! Your reply helped me solve the issue. I do need to initialize it on page load. Thank you!